Windows 11 google-chrome - yahoo search browser hijack
In Windows 11, chrome browser, google search redirected to yahoo search likely caused by a malware or browser hijack.
How to remove the malware or fix this problem? GRATEFUL!
I tried, clearing all chrome cache + disable yahoo search + setting google search as default (either or both in chrome setting or windows setting); maybe work a short while and problem came back.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That’s odd malware for a redirect to go from Google to Yahoo, that suggests, it’s not necessarily a malicious redirect
